# TypeError: this.state.votes.map is not a function when calling function that increment number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I`m a newbie in React and I am currently building a voting system.

When I am pressing the voting button i get this error: TypeError: this.state.votes.map is not a function

This is the code that I`ve written:

```
import React from 'react';

class Lista extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    items:["React","Vue","Angular","Ember"],
    votes:[0,0,0,0]
    
};


}

  Increment1 = () => {
   this.setState({votes : this.state.votes[0] + 1})
}

  Increment2 = () => {
   this.setState({votes : this.state.votes[1] + 1})
}
  Increment3 = () => {
   this.setState({votes : this.state.votes[2] + 1})
}
  Increment4 = () => {
   this.setState({votes : this.state.votes[3] + 1})

}
  render() {
   return(
    <React.Fragment>
 <div style={{display:'flex',alignItems:'center'}}>
 <ul>
    {this.state.items.map(x => (
        <li>{x}</li>
       
  ))}


 </ul>


 <ul style={{listStyleType:'none'}}>


    {this.state.votes.map(y =>(
        <li>{y}</li>
    ))}
    

 </ul>

 <ul style={{listStyleType:'none'}}>
 <li><button onClick={this.Increment1}>Vote</button></li>

 <li><button onClick={this.Increment2}>Vote</button></li>

 <li><button onClick={this.Increment3}>Vote</button></li>

 <li><button onClick={this.Increment4}>Vote</button></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 </React.Fragment>
);
}



}




export default Lista;
```

I googled the error but I found examples that the object is not array type this.state.votes[0] but votes is array of int.

Please help

Comment: When you have an error, give the line (and maybe column) of the error, it is easier to locate the bug like this

Comment: > 57 | <ul style={{listStyleType:'none'}}>

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
this.setState({votes : this.state.votes[0] + 1})
```

completely replaces your `votes` array with the result of the addition.

If you're going to modify the entries separately like that, you probably want to have separate counts in state rather than using an array.

But if you want to use an array, you'll need to update the whole thing, which is best done with the callback form of `setState` (because state updates may be asynchronous and may be batched together, so you need the most up-to-date version of it):

```
this.setState(({votes}) => {
    votes = votes.slice();
    ++votes[0];
    return votes;
});
```

I should note that you *can* do that with one complicated expression rather than a couple of statements:

```
this.setState(({votes}) => Object.assign(votes.slice(), {0: votes[0] + 1}));
```

...but that's probably a bit harder to read.

In both cases, just change the `0` to `1` or `2` or `3` as needed. Perhaps have a single function that accepts an index:

```
function increment(votes, index) {
    votes = votes.slice();
    ++votes[index];
    return votes;
}
```

...and use that in your various handlers.

You can also use `[...votes]` instead of `votes.slice()` to make the copy of the array if you like. They do the same thing in slightly different ways (provided it's not a *sparse* array, which yours isn't).

Answer (score 0):

```js
// ...

Increment1 = () => {
   this.setState({votes: [this.state.votes[0] + 1, this.state.votes.slice(1)]})
}

Increment2 = () => {
   this.setState({votes: [this.state.votes[0], this.state.votes[1] + 1, this.state.votes.slice(2)]})
}

// ...
```

Actually you are overriding type of votes from an array to a number, you've to set the state of votes as an array. I've attached sample code you can improve it or use it as is.